# ui-bootstrap tooltip doesn't work when used with ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, tooltip, angular-ui

I would like to use the `ui-bootstrap tooltip` directive to assign tooltips to an array of buttons which are rendered by an `ng-repeat` directive, like this:

```
<button ng-repeat="label in labels" tooltip="{{label}}">{{label}}</button>
```

but I'm facing a strange issue: the ng-repeat loop variable gets a blank value, except that in the tooltip itself, so for example in the above example the label value would be blank in the button.
A snippet showing the issue could be seen at [this link](http://plnkr.co/edit/5LvfDXUcnvP6e7xDfW0T?p=preview). 
Everything is ok removing the tooltip attribute.
Is there anyone who has been using ui-bootstrap and knows about such issues?

Comment: SunnyShah answered your question already, but just one remark: you don't need to include bootstrap's JavaScript to use angular-ui/bootstrap. More info here: https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap#project-philosophy

Comment: @pkozlowski.opensource, Thanks for this information. It got me interested in AngularUI project. You got one github star and one user/contributor. ;)

Comment: @pkozlowski.opensource, Can you please put this in **BOLD** in github page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using old angular-ui lib, This one seems like a bug of Angular-Ui, Looks like they have Fixed it in current version.

Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/wSzIjgq6JDAAY06iNGrG?p=preview

Comment: I noticed in the Plunker that you just updated Angular to last version, not angular-ui, and you substituted ui-bootstrap with the tls version. Anyway, it solved my issue, thanks.